# Trouble with Node-Red and node.js version running in a netns

Tags: node.js, node-red, nvm, linux-namespaces

I need to **run node-red in a netns** I created. I have a dedicated modem interface in this namespace that only node-red should have access to.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and installed npm -> then nvm version manager for node.js to install 8.11.3 and then node-red itself.

I only installed nvm version 8.11.3 and set that as default. I would expect that to be the only version running anywhere.

[image: Picture showing the output of nvm ls]

When I launch node-red from a regular shell it launches with node.js version 8.11.3

When I launch node-red in the netns it also launches with node.js version 8.11.3 [I use the -u /directory option to run the same flow as normal user]

**Problem:**
When I launch node-red in the netns from an automated shell script it launches with node.js version 4.9.1 instead [I use the -u /directory option to run the same flow as normal user]

```
Welcome to Node-RED
===================

21 Jun 11:42:15 - [info] Node-RED version: v0.18.7
21 Jun 11:42:15 - [info] **Node.js  version: v4.2.6**
21 Jun 11:42:15 - [info] Linux 4.13.0-45-generic x64 LE
```

The launch line in the script is:

`ip netns exec sensor node-red -u /home/iotdemo/.node-red`

"sensor" is the netns name, and the -u option is pointing to the same directory for the flows as a normal user.

Why does it launch with a node.js version I don't even have installed and how to I get it to launch with the desired v8.11.3 ?

I suspect it has something to do with root versus user (iotdemo) , but it seems to launch a process in a namespace you must do it as root.

Thanks for your consideration of this problem.

Comment: What happens if you run `node -version` as root?

Comment: @hardillb If I type sudo node -v the output is correctly showing v8.11.3  ; If I type sudo su - and then run node -v I get the old version show up as v4.2.6

Comment: That doesn't change the environment, run `sudo su -` then run `node -version`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By installing npm you must have installed NodeJS at the same time as a prereq (since npm is just another NodeJS app).

This means you have a system level install of NodeJS at version v4.2.6

nvm just messes with a users path to insert a search path before the system bin directories (e.g. /bin /usr/bin /usr/local/bin) and then maintains a set of symlinks that point to different versions of NodeJS. Since you set everything up as the user iotdemo then only this user will have the nvm path enabled, which is why the root user is still seeing the system installed version of NodeJS.

The simplest option will be to write a script that uses `su` to run node-red as the iotdemo user and pass this to the ip netns exec command.

e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm exec 8.11.3 node-red
```

Then call this script

```
ip netns exec sensor su - iotdemo -c /path/to/script
```

See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184508/nvm-command-not-available-in-bash-script) for details of getting nvm to work in scripts.

Comment: I follow your instruction above , and I get node-red to launch by calling the script but it still shows v4.2.6 running even though the user directory and settings file are pointed to /home/iotdemo/.node-red

Comment: I've updated the script to explicitly force nvm to use a version

Comment: That generates an error that I noticed before - I tried calling nvm from the script but it doesn't run. In the case of following your directions I get: exec: nvm: command not found. Actually if I try to execute nvm as root I get 'command not found' so for whatever reason nvm is not usable as root

Comment: nvm is not running as root in my example, it should be running as iotdemo and the the `-` after su should ensure that iotdemo's environment is setup correctly

Comment: OK, looks like nvm is a shell command not a script/executable. Try the new version of the script and `ip netns` command

Comment: Thanks for the ideas - it works with the two script approach!  Do you think there is a way to keep this working in a single script? I tried calling the nvm shell in my bash script then executing the last line in the namespace but it doesn't work...

Comment: It is a single script, it's just sourcing the setup. Also https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I need to have a separate script with those two lines to call from the original script I was working on. I meant is there a way to embed that in my original scrip having one less file to maintain. That would be a more elegant solution, but the one suggested definitely works so I marked question as answered. Thx!